# Random Forest sklearn - Equals values predict

Tags: random-forest, prediction

House Prices challenge Kaggle 
I'm trying to predict prices with RandomForestClassifier. After predict it results same prices for all id. Do you have an idea of the problem ?

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
clf.score(X_train, y_train)
X = df_test2[feature_cols]    
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
df_imp = imp.fit_transform(X)
df_test_scale = scaler.transform(df_imp)
y_pred = clf.predict(df_test_scale)
predict_prices = pd.DataFrame({"Id" : df_test2['Id'], "SalePrice":y_pred})
predict_prices
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have scaled the training set, scale test set with same scaler.

Comment: I tought I had done this step. Do you know where to add it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Change as below:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
X_train_imp=imp.Transform(X_train)
X_train_scaled=scaler.transform(X_train_imp)
clf = clf.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)
clf.score(X_train, y_train)
X = df_test2[feature_cols]    
df_imp = imp.fit_transform(X)
df_test_scale = scaler.transform(df_imp)
y_pred = clf.predict(df_test_scale)
predict_prices = pd.DataFrame({"Id" : df_test2['Id'], "SalePrice":y_pred})
predict_prices
```